Detect scroll past elements with same class and highlight anchor in menu
I'm trying to detect whenever a visitor has scrolled past elements on a page.
I would like to detect scrolling past every .title element, and add an .active class to the corresponding anchor menu item. The .active class should stay on the anchor menu item until scrolling past the next title element.
Here is what I have - adding the .active class works, but removing it fails.
Anyone able to help?
JsFiddle here.


window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  document.querySelectorAll('.title').forEach((section) => {
    const id = section.getAttribute('id');
    if (id) {
      if (window.scrollY > (section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight)) {
        document.querySelector(`.menu li a[href="#${id}"]`).classList.add('active');
      } else {
        document.querySelector(`.menu li a.active`).classList.remove('active');
      }
    }
  });
});
.active {
  color: red
}
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#one">Link one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#two">Link two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#three">Link thre</a></li>
  <li><a href="#four">Link four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#five">Link five</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div class="title" id="one">Title one</div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.

    Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
  </p>
  <div class="title" id="two">Title two</div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.

    Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
  </p>
  <div class="title" id="three">Title three</div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.

    Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
  </p>
  <div class="title" id="four">Title four</div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.

    Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
  </p>
  <div class="title" id="five">Title five</div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis.

    Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla et leo diam.
  </p>
</div>




Try to add this script i think it should work we need one function to check if an element is in the viewport.


window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  let activeMenuItem = null;
  
  // Iterate through each .title element
  document.querySelectorAll('.title').forEach((section) => {
    const id = section.getAttribute('id');
    
    if (id) {
      // Check if the user has scrolled past this .title element
      if (window.scrollY > (section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight)) {
        // If scrolled past, mark the current .title's corresponding menu item as active
        activeMenuItem = document.querySelector(`.menu li a[href="#${id}"]`);
      }
    }
  });

  // Remove active class from all menu items
  document.querySelectorAll('.menu li a').forEach((menuItem) => {
    menuItem.classList.remove('active');
  });

  // Add active class only to the last identified menu item
  if (activeMenuItem) {
    activeMenuItem.classList.add('active');
  }
});




This is perfect. Thank you so much!

The provided code is almost correct, but it fails to remove the .active class from the previous menu item when scrolling past a new title element. The issue lies in the else block of the scroll event listener, where the code attempts to remove the .active class from all elements with the class .menu li a.active.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

With modern browsers; you should use an Intersection Observer ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API
Here I added classes to the menu items just for clarity; then toggled the active class when the titles come into or leave the view.  I also gave the container a size to make it apparent and have a scroll as to what is in the "view" for that; attaching the observer to each of the titles based on that class.  A bit more verbose than needed but done so for clarity in the code.


const options = {
  threshold: 0.4,
};
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const titles = document.querySelectorAll('.title');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    const t = entry.target;
    const tID = t.id;
    const tSel = `.menu-item[href="#${tID}"]`;
    const menuItem = menu.querySelector(`${tSel}`);
    //  console.log(`MI:${menuItem}`);
    const isIntersecting = entry.isIntersecting;
    t.classList.toggle('active', isIntersecting);
    menuItem.classList.toggle('active', isIntersecting);
  }, options);
});

titles.forEach(title => observer.observe(title));
.menu-item.active {
  color: #FF0000;
  border: solid 1px #ff0000;
}

.title.active {
  color: #00a0a0;
  border: solid 1px #00a0a0;
}

.container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a class="menu-item" href="#one">Link one</a></li>
  <li><a class="menu-item" href="#two">Link two</a></li>
  <li><a class="menu-item" href="#three">Link three</a></li>
  <li><a class="menu-item" href="#four">Link four</a></li>
  <li><a class="menu-item" href="#five">Link five</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div class="title" id="one">Title one</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus
    fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales
    risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis. Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum
    ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor
    ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla
    et leo diam.</p>
  <div class="title" id="two">Title two</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus
    fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales
    risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis. Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum
    ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor
    ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla
    et leo diam.</p>
  <div class="title" id="three">Title three</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus
    fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales
    risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis. Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum
    ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor
    ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla
    et leo diam.</p>
  <div class="title" id="four">Title four</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus
    fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales
    risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis. Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum
    ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor
    ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla
    et leo diam.</p>
  <div class="title" id="five">Title five</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec cursus dolor id ullamcorper tempor. Donec ut ullamcorper tellus. Etiam vel rhoncus urna. Aenean augue nulla, congue a orci at, imperdiet vehicula eros. Aenean ornare nibh ut leo faucibus
    fringilla. Quisque varius ut ipsum egestas feugiat. Mauris id nisl ultrices, consectetur mauris in, consectetur mi. Sed sit amet dolor urna. Nullam nec enim gravida, pulvinar lacus ut, volutpat nibh. Quisque commodo eu tortor ac dictum. Vivamus sodales
    risus sed blandit vulputate. Proin elit erat, varius non tincidunt ut, semper sed erat. Nulla vehicula vitae nisl nec dignissim. Curabitur viverra risus eu est pellentesque lobortis. Nullam egestas semper convallis. Ut ac blandit risus, sit amet elementum
    ex. Donec rhoncus augue eu cursus consequat. Duis a sapien sit amet elit aliquet molestie. Mauris nec ligula viverra, ornare dolor vel, malesuada nisl. Proin gravida dolor justo, sit amet tempus justo consectetur ut. Aenean malesuada iaculis tortor
    ac varius. Phasellus ultrices purus nisi, eu rutrum felis bibendum id. Phasellus enim dui, ultrices sed massa vel, euismod bibendum eros. Duis quis auctor augue, eget pellentesque velit. In a est at neque dignissim pellentesque et tempus sem. Nulla
    et leo diam.</p>
</div>



